# Yii create table from application

Tags: yii

In my yii aplication we need to create dynamic table.
so i hav used like below:

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CREATE TABLE {$tokenid}( `column1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `column2` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`column1`) ); ");
```

But it's not working. Any suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the command,

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CREATE TABLE {$tokenid}( column1 INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, column2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (column1) ); ")->execute();
```

or look at the create table function http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#createTable-detail

Answer (score 4):

You should use [createTable()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#createTable-detail) for this. An example from the [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.query-builder#building-schema-manipulation-queries):

```
// CREATE TABLE `tbl_user` (
//     `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
//     `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
//     `location` point
// ) ENGINE=InnoDB
createTable('tbl_user', array(
    'id' => 'pk',
    'username' => 'string NOT NULL',
    'location' => 'point',
), 'ENGINE=InnoDB')
```